# A puzzling example about the C keyword "restrict"

Tags: c, keyword, restrict

[The example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) is taken from Wikipedia:

```
void updatePtrs(size_t *restrict ptrA, size_t *restrict ptrB, size_t *restrict val)
{
    *ptrA += *val;
    *ptrB += *val;
}
```

I call this function in the `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 10; 
    size_t j = 0;

    updatePtrs(&i, &j, &i);

    printf("i = %lu\n", i); 
    printf("j = %lu\n", j); 

    return 0;
}
```

The `val` pointer is not be loaded twice according to the Wikipedia's description, so the value of `j` should be 10, but it's 20 in fact.

Is my comprehension about this keyword not correct? Should I utilize some specific options of `gcc`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behaviour. `restrict` is a promise from you to the compiler that all of the pointer parameters point to different memory areas.

You break this promise by putting `&i` for two of the arguments.

(In fact, with `restrict` it is allowed to pass overlapping pointers, but only if no writes are done through any of the overlapping pointers within the function. But typically you would not bother with `restrict` if there is no writing happening).

---

FWIW, on my system with gcc 4.9.2, output is `j = 20` at `-O0` and `j = 10` at `-O1` or higher, which suggests that the compiler is indeed taking note of the `restrict`.  Of course, since it is undefined behaviour, your results may vary.

Comment: I just want to comprehend this keyword, so I break the promise. it gets 10 if utilize "-O1" for gcc(5.2.1).